# Regex matching bracket when it should not

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, tags

With the input:

> "a[href*=\"test\"]"

I am attempting to match the tag name from the following jQuery selector:

```
Regex r = new Regex("^[A-z]+");
string tagName = r.Match("a[href*=\"test\"]").Value;
```

The issue is that it collects the left bracket instead of just A through z:

> tagName = "a[href"

Why would it collect the bracket if it was not specified in the expression?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because this

```
[A-z]
```

Creates a character range from ASCII 'A' to ASCII 'z'. There are characters other than letters between Z and a, one of them being the `[` character. Use instead:

```
[A-Za-z]
```

To match the range from `A-Z` *and* the range from `a-z`, but not the characters that fall in between them. You can look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to see the specifics, but the summary is that the characters (in their numerical ASCII order) look like this:

```
A, B, ..., Y, Z, [, \, ], ^, _, `, a, b, c, ..., z
```

Comment: @John, if it solves your issue you should accept the answer as being the correct one. (Check the mark below the votes for this answer, so that the checkmark becomes green.)

Answer (score -1):

You should try a tool like regexpal to test stuff like this.  Here's your example:

http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=^%5BA-z%5D%2B&input=a%5Bhref*%3D%5C%22test%5C%22%5D

What's weird to me is the lower case "z" - for some reason, that is allowing the bracket to pass.

Try this:

```
^[^\[]+
```

http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=^%5B^%5C%5B%5D%2B&input=a%5Bhref*%3D%5C%22test%5C%22%5D

Comment: I’m not the downvoter, but I assume the vote happened because you did not, in fact, provide an answer to the question (**Why** would it collect the bracket when it was not specified in the expression?). Providing a workaround and admitting oneself baffled by the issue is –1 in many people’s books if the issue is such a basic one as it it is here.